# Parse HTML using beautiful soup & render template in jinja2

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I'm trying to parse a local HTML document using beautiful soup, then `render_template()` the result using jinja2.

I'm new to python, but here's what I'm trying:

```
@app.route("inherit/index")
def inheritIndex():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("templates/index.html"), "html.parser")
    soup.find(text="foobar").replaceWith("Hooray!")
    return render_template(soup)
```

Comment: What is a problem ? BTW. `render_template` expects filename not BS object. Maybe you need [render_template_string()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.render_template_string)

Comment: My issue is trying to render a jinja2 template from something that has been parsed using BS. Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't help.

Comment: BS can give you result as HTML string and you can save it in file to use it with `render_template(filename)` or try to use this HTML string directly with `render_template_string(html_string)`

Comment: or put `{{ foobar }}` in `index.html` and use `render_template("templates/index.html", foobar="Hooray!")`

Comment: Your suggestion worked great for me. I didn't realise I could substitute values right from the `render_template()` method. Thank you!

Comment: so now you have to read more about templates [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to substitute the values right from within the `render_template()` method. BeautifulSoup was not required. Here was my solution as suggested in the comments.

HTML:

```
...
<p> {{ foobar }} lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
...
```

Python:

```
@app.route("inherit/index")
    def inheritIndex():
    return render_template("index.html", foobar="Hooray!")

    # <p> Hooray! lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
```